Op amp Inverter Amplifier
In the following circuits, ideal op-amps are used:

Circuit 1 - The non-inverting input is grounded through a 2 kilo ohm resistor.
Circuit 2 - The non-inverting input is grounded directly.

Are the output voltages the same in both circuits or not?

What do you  think?

What do you think - and WHY?

I want to know, is there any effect of a 2 kilo ohm resistor on voltage gain?

What kind of opamp have you?

Looks like homework. Smells like homework ... The point of homework is for you to figure it out, not for someone else to give you the answer.

No No This is not a homework. I created this question. My suggestion is this "An ideal op-amp has infinite input impedance, meaning it draws no current from the input source. Therefore, the resistor connected to the non-inverting terminal wouldn't create any loading effects on the input signal."

That's not answering the question though.

Therefore, the resistor connected to the non-inverting terminal wouldn't create any loading effects on the input signal. does this have any relationship with the gain equation?

Circuit 1 should have the same voltage as circuit 2, except for a "very little" offset added by the 2k resistor (bias offset).

Yes, they are same because there will be no input current at +,- terminals in the ideal op-amp. So there will be no current flow across the 2k ohm resistor, so it will act as a short circuit. Since voltage at + terminal of both cases will be zero and other components in the circuits are same as the result output of both will be equal.

Since the op-amp is ideal, then you can make the assumption that input resistance is infinite, and so its inputs sink/source no current. In a schematic, that might look like this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Firstly, since node A is grounded, then obviously the potential at A is:
$$ V_A = 0V $$
Due to infinite op-amp input resistance, input current \$I\$ is zero:
$$ I = 0A $$
Input current \$I\$, according to KCL, must pass via R1. By Ohm's law, the potential difference \$V_R\$ across resistor R1 is:
$$ V_R = I \times R_1 = 0A \times 2k\Omega = 0V $$
Using KVL we can calculate the potential at B:
$$ V_B = V_A - V_R = 0V - 0V = 0V $$
Intuitively, for ideal op-amps with infinite input resistance, there can be no input current, and the presence of a resistance in that path of (no) current will have no voltage across it, and the potentials either side of the resistor will be the same.
Consequently, with or without that 2kΩ resistance, circuit behaviour is identical.
This will not be true for real-life op-amps, since they all have finite input resistance, resulting in so-called "input bias current" which typically ranges from picoamps to microamps, depending on the model.
